# Large Windows in Apache Beam pipeline

Tags: apache-beam

I have a high-level question regarding window sizes in apache beam. Most streaming examples show using beam with relatively small window sizes. Our use case involves looking at data that encompasses 15 to 30-day windows.

My question is does anyone foresee any downside to have windows this large?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a 15-day window, this would require buffering up data for 15 days before finally producing an answer. Most people with streaming pipelines are interested in latencies lower than that.

You could look at using sliding windows with a lower offset, e.g. [sliding windows](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#sliding-time-windows) that produces data for the past 15 days ever day. If the ratio of the window size to sliding duration is large, this requires storing many intermediates per key (e.g. 15-day/1-hour sliding windows would require 15*24 intermediates).

You could also use [triggers](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#triggers) to get speculative data out before the windows is "complete." Using triggers you'd could get data *N* days into the full window, constantly growing until the window was finally done 15 days later.  This requires greater care in handling "early" results to avoid double counting (e.g. one wouldn't want to include emitted "day 1 sum" and "day 1-2 sum" into the same aggregation).

Comment: The trigger approach seems the most promissing. Thanks for the response!